# Appwrite - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endpoint')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, appwrite

i'm making a project with Appwrite and i have a problem regarding SKD´s.
When use a client-side SDK to use the functions of Appwrite Teams it works perfectly, like this:

```
import { Client, Teams } from "appwrite";
const client = new Client();
client
    .setEndpoint(..some project info..)
    .setProject(....) 
;

const teams = new Teams(client);

const promise = teams.list(); //Works without a problem
```

But now i'm trying to use a server-side SDK to basically do the same:

```
const sdk = require('node-appwrite');
const client = new sdk.Client();
client
    .setEndpoint(..same project info..)
    .setProject(...)
    .setKey(...)
;

const teams = new Teams(client);

const promise = teams.list(); //Error
```

But i get this error:
[image: error]

am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try:

```js
const teams = new sdk.Teams(client);
```

Comment: It was exactly the problem, thank you